# Exporting data from jqgrid to excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, export-to-excel

Hi i want to export the data present in my jQgrid in one of my asp.net web application into excel sheet i looked around the net and i find only sites that tell me how to do it for MVC application and this is not wat i want. I tried doing this but i am getting some error in my global.asax file.
i added a button in my web page and on click of it  i am doing this.

```
 protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        grdLateFeeConfiguration.ExportToExcel("BlockedUsers.xls");
    }
```

and i get an exception here in my global.asax file

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = (HttpException)exception;
        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        Application["errorInfor"] = httpCode;

    }
```

The exception object that is returned by the `Server.GetLasrError()` method is always null and i get a null pointer exception when `httpException.GetHttpCode();` i dont understand wat is happening can someone explain wat is happening.

Comment: Probably [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) provide the solution.

Comment: i am sorry i dont understand.

Comment: [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) provide the code which shows how to export data to Excel file (XLSX) from ASP.NET MVC application. [The demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel.zip) demonstrate it and combines displaing of data in jqGrid with exporting the data. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExportToExcel.zip) are used as pure ASHX handler and can be used in any ASP.NET application.

Comment: Dear @oleg i tried doing it with the method `DataForExcel(string[] headers, DataType[] colunmTypes, List<string[]> data,
             string sheetName)` as suggested by you but i still get the same error in exactly the same location i showed above is it possible to export the data from the client side and not the server side?

Comment: Do you used my demo project? In which line you get the error? The security of web browser allows you to download from any web site Excel file and to open it directly in Microsoft Excel installed locally, but  there are no JavaScript function which would allow you to create binary file (.XLSX) and to start associated program Excel. All the restrictions exists because of security reason.

Comment: I did not get error in your code, I am getting an error in the Global.asax file Error `Message:Session state is not available in this context`

Comment: @Oleg I did not get error in your code, I am getting an error in the Global.asax file Error Message:Session state is not available in this context

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your implementation and I don't understand why you modified `Global.asax`.

Comment: Hi @Oleg This problem was occurring due to the <asp:UpdatePannel-- control when i removed the update panel the export functionality is working fine

Comment: @Oleg is it possible to format the data that is sent as a response to the export so that the data that appears in the excel sheet just as it appears in the jqgrid

Comment: The code from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) which I referenced before shows how to assign `StyleIndex` property of the cell and how to define different styles. So you can produce any format like you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was occurring due to the presence of UpdatePannel control when this was removed it worked fine.