# jQgrid : How to Export Jqgrid table data to Excel File in asp.net MVC 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application which uses JQgrid to generate tables.

I also need to Export my Grid data to an Excel File.Is it possible in Jqgrid. I searched in `'trirand'` and i cant see any jQgrid demo to export grid data.

Should i use any library to Export data to Excel or is there any feature available in Jqgrid to Export data.

Any help is appreciated.

Script

```
$("#Grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#Pager', {
                caption: "Export to Excel",
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-save", 
                onClickButton: function () {
                    var gridData = $("#Grid").jqGrid('getRowData');
                    var dataToSend = JSON.stringify(gridData);
                    jQuery("#Grid").jqGrid('excelExport', dataToSend);
                }
            });
```

Here i am trying to Export Json Data to Excel Format. But i am getting some error in grid.import.js file.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null ---  grid.import.js:208
```

Comment: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935). [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) shows how the visibility of the exported data can be improved.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Oleg . I tried in different way ,because i want to do all the (Excel Export) processing to be done from Client Side itself to reduce Server Load. Please see my updated post.