# jqgrid export to excel is giving incorrect data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have custom button to filer the jqgrid. Onpage load grid gives me 100 records. If I export to excel I got 100 records correctly. Then I filter the jqgrid and grid shows me 10 records. But if I export to excel I got 100 records which I got previously.

Below is my code for filter.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    search: true,
    postData: {filters: filter},
    sortname: 'statusCode',
    sortorder: 'asc'
});

$("#grid").setGridParam({page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
var gridData = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

In gridData I got 100 object each time irrespective of any filter. I need only records to be export which are displayed in grid after filtration.

Please suggest solution how I can get 10 records from grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can get the value of new `lastSelectedData` parameter instead of the value of `data` parameter. See [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm) [at the end](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#some-demos-which-demonstrates-new-features) of the readme. The most new features are described in the readme or in [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

Comment: Thanks Oleg .                                                                                                               I am trying below code.                                                              $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    search: true,
    postData: {filters: filter},
    sortname: 'statusCode',
    sortorder: 'asc'
});

$("#grid").setGridParam({page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
var gridData = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','lastSelectedData');                                            But still I am not getting expected result

Comment: @MohanThakare: You are welcome! Are you sure that you use `datatype: "local"` or the grid have `loadonce: true` and you make **local** filtering of data? In general if the problem do exist you can provide the demo which reproduce the problem. Having the demo I can quickly find the reason in your code of to find the bug in free jqGrid and to fix it. Do you tried [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/GetFilteredData.htm)? One can set any filter and then click "Show filterd and sorted data (Ids and Client name)" button. You will see all the filtered and sorted data.

Comment: My data type is datatype: 'json' and loadonce: true. I can not change data type. I will try some demo and share it.

Comment: @MohanThakare: You can create JSFiddle demo for example. The demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/78m7jdaz/3/ shows how to use Echo service of JSFiddle to create the demo with `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true`. The `serverResponse` posted to the server as `postData: {json: JSON.stringify(serverResponse)}` informs Echo service which data should be returned. You can modify the demo, save it and send me the URL.

Comment: @MohanThakare: You can use the latest free jqGrid code (see "External Resources" on the left side). See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit)

Comment: Still not able to resolve the issue. My basic problem is getting the filtered data from jqgrid in json format.

Comment: One more thing is there. Please confirm. jqgrid does not have export facility?

Comment: @MohanThakare: jqGrid is pure JavaScript (jQuery plugin) solution. So one can't implement clean and browser independent export in Excel, Pdf and so on. One needs generate **binary data** for such export. One should just send information about the ids of filtered data to the server and the server should generate the exported binary files with the items. [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) described my point of view to the problem.

Comment: I have raised separate question . url is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098034/how-to-get-jqgrid-filtered-data-in-json-format