# jqGrid export to excel issue when loadonce option is setted to false

Tags: excel, jqgrid, export-to-excel, paging

I have an ASP.net MVC solution and use jqGrid in it. To have a better performance I use `loadonce: false` as an option and it should be in this way, unfortunately It seems to be not supported by jqGrid because I cannot find any sign of that throughout my search.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid(
        {
            url: "/Student/GetStudents",
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",

            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                id: "StudentId",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            colNames: ['StudentId', 'FirstName', 'LastName'],
            colModel: [
                { label: 'StudentId', name: 'Id', key: true, width: 75 },
                { label: 'FirstName', name: 'FirstName', width: 150 },
                { label: 'LastName', name: 'LastName', width: 150 },

            ],
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: false,
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [20, 30, 50],
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'Id',
            pager: "#jqGridPager",

            autoencode: true,
            scroll: false,
            pgbuttons: true,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            forceFit: false,
            gridview: false,
            height: '100%',
            scrollrows: true,
            page: 1,
            //pagerpos: 'center',
            toppager: true,
            recordpos: 'right',
            multiselect: true,
            multiboxonly: true,
            direction: 'rtl',
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: "",
            rownumbers: true
        });
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager', {
        search: true,
        searchtext: "Search",
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        excel: true,
        refresh: false,

    }, {}, {}, {}, {
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        multipleSearch: false,
        multipleGroup: false,
        showQuery: false,
        sopt: ['cn', 'eq', 'ne'],
        defaultSearch: 'cn'
    })
    $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#jqGridPager', {
        caption: "Export to Excel",
        //buttonicon: "ui-icon-disk",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-folder-open",
        onClickButton: function () {
            exportToExcel();
        },

    });
});
function exportToExcel(data, e) {
    exportExcelFile(data);
}


function exportExcelFile() {
    debugger;

    var data = $('#jqGrid')[0].addLocalData(true);
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        frame1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
        frame1.document.write(setTableOfData(data));
        frame1.document.close();
        frame1.focus();
        sa = frame1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "text.xls");
    } else
        $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('exportToExcel', { fileName: "exportedExcel.xls", navigator: true });
}

function setTableOfData(data) {
    var htmlString = '<table>';
    var header = '<tr><td>StudentId</td><td>FirstName</td><td>LastName</td></tr>';
    htmlString += header;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var tag = '<tr><td>' + data[i].Id + '</td><td>' + data[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' + data[i].LastName + '</td></tr>';
        htmlString += tag;
    }
    htmlString += '</table>';
    return htmlString;
}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? You write about the bad performance of jqGrid in case of usage `loadonce: true`. It sounds strange. How many total number of rows need be displayed? You have the data on the server, then it's better that the *server code* export to Excel. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935).

Comment: Currently I use version 4.4 of jqGrid but I find export option in versions above 4.8 so I`ll upgrade it. I have over 21 grid in my entire solution and each one has different setting (url, postData, ...) so I am trying to avoid several server side method instead of one client side method. In addition I use free jqGrid.

Comment: The current version of free jqGrid is 4.13.6 (not 4.8). The version 4.4.4 is 4 years old and it's dead since many years. I don't understand your statement: "I am trying to avoid several server side method instead of one client side method". Do you want to have server side sorting or the client side sorting? How many rows of data need be displayed? In case of small number of rows (<1000) one should use client side paging, sorting and filtering. It works much more quickly as on server side. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) with 5000 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I forced to post all the filtering and other settings of the grid to the server and return a link to the client. Then with the given link I became able to download the excel file.
Info: you can not download a file with post(ajax) request.