# JqGrid free display not working in chrome as it does nicely in IE 11

Tags: google-chrome, jqgrid

I tried to figure out what's wrong with current test code I've played with jqGrid free. I have evaluated a few and I have to pick jqGrid as it is so flexible to use it.
    However, I have this issue, so I'm not sure whether or not it comes from the js set I'm using or something else since I'm doing it a little bit differently. I'm using inline editing. And weird as it is, it displays nicely in IE 11 and horribly in Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (32-bit). 
    Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>


<title>Test jqGrid free</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css ">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/plugins/css/ui.multiselect.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/plugins/min/ui.multiselect.js"></script>         




<script type="text/javascript">


      var URL = 'group.json';



    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.inlineEdit, {

        });
    $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
                datatype: 'json',
                jsonReader : {
                    repeatitems:false
                },
                height: 'auto',
                viewrecords: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                altRows: true,
                loadError: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            });

jQuery.extend(
    jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
        mtype: 'PUT',
        EditData: function(postData) {
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        }
    }
);



$(document)
.ready(

    function() {
        $("#list")
                .jqGrid(
                        {
                            url : URL,
                            datatype : 'json',
                            mtype : 'GET'

 ,
 serializeRowData: function (postdata) {

        var json = JSON.stringify(postdata);

            return json;

},  
                            colNames : ['Code', 'Name','Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul',
                                    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                             colModel : [ 
                            {
                                name : 'projectCode',
                                index : 'projectCode',
                                width : 70,
                                editable : false

                            }, {
                                name : 'projectName',
                                index : 'projectName',
                                width : 120,
                                editable : false
                           }, {
                                name : 'january', 
                                index : 'january',
                                width : 60,
                                editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'february', 
                                index : 'february',
                                width : 60,
                               editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'march',
                                index : 'march',
                                width : 60,
                               editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'april',
                                index : 'april',
                                width : 60,
                                editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'may',
                                index : 'may',
                                width : 60,
                                editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'june',
                                index : 'june',
                                width : 60,
                                editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'july',
                                index : 'july',
                                width : 60,
                                 editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'august',
                                index : 'july',
                                width : 60,
                               editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'september',
                                index : 'september',
                                width : 60,
                                 editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'october',
                                index : 'october',
                                width : 60,
                                 editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'november',
                                index : 'november',
                                width : 60,
                                 editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            }, {
                                name : 'december',
                                index : 'december',
                                width : 60,
                                 editable : true,
                                editoptions: {
                                      defaultValue: '0'
                                }                        
                            } ],
                            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                            rownumbers: true,                                                       
                            pager : '#pager',
                            rowNum : 25,
                            rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],

                            grouping: true,
                            groupingView: {
                                groupField: ["projectName"],
                                groupColumnShow: [true],
                                groupText: ["<b>{0}</b>"],
                                groupOrder: ["asc"],
                                groupSummary: [true],
                                groupCollapse: false
                            },
                           viewrecords : true,
                             caption : 'Test',
                            editurl: URL, 
                           editable: true,
                            datatype : 'json',
                        }

                        )
            .jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', 
                    {
                        edit : false,
                        add : false,
                        del : false,
                        search : false
                    }
                    )                       
;



        function reload(rowid, result) {
            console.log('inside reload');
          $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
        };

        var reloadGridFunc = function () {
             var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 500);
        };  


        var editoptions = {         
            keys: true,   
            mtype: "PUT",
            url: URL + '/1',    
            successfunc: reloadGridFunc
        };  


        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: false, 
        groupHeaders:[
        {startColumnName: 'projectCode', numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: '<em>Project</em>'},
            {startColumnName: 'january', numberOfColumns: 12, titleText: 'Calendar'}
        ]
        }),         

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", {
        add:true,
        edit:true,
        save:true,
            addParams: {
            position: "last",
                addRowParams: editoptions
           },
            editParams: editoptions

        });

    })

            ;


        // Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
        (function() {
            var method;
            var noop = function () {};
            var methods = [
                'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
                'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
                'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
                'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
            ];
            var length = methods.length;
            var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

            while (length--) {
                method = methods[length];

                // Only stub undefined methods.
                if (!console[method]) {
                    console[method] = noop;
                }
            }
        }());           
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <br/> <br/>
        <div id="pager"></div>
        <table id="list"></table>


  <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Below are the images for IE and Chrome
IE: [Good diplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjyCP.jpg)

Chrome : [Not quite expected display as for IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQABQ.jpg)

As for json data , I use it like below:

```
{
    "rows":
    [
        {"projectCode":"A","projectName":"Project A","january":1.0,"february":0.0,"march":0.0,"april":0.0,"may":0.0,"june":0.0,"july":0.0,"august":0.0,"september":0.0,"october":0.0,"november":0.0,"december":1.0}
    ]
}
```

Did I overlook something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add always the line

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

before

```html
<html>
```

in all HTML5 documents.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. That solved the issue I'm having. How obvious and I did not pay attention to it since it was working with IE without the missing tag.

Comment: @LuckyRiver: You are welcome! I'd recommend you to look at some examples from [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). Additionally you should clean-up your code. It contains a lot of error, like double `datatype` property for one object and so on. It's good to place `"use strict";` at the beginning of your code or at the beginning of outer function to see more errors. Tools like jshint (http://jshint.com/) for example can help you to find syntax problems.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Much appreciated. I'm new to the jqGrid. I check the tools. Btw, is the functionality export to Excel is supported with jqGrid free?

Comment: @LuckyRiver: You are welcome! One can export the data on the server side (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9349688/315935) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13957161/315935)) or to use other existing products like [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). See [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ovq05x0c/6/) of usage. See [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/417) for more details.

Comment: Hi Oleg,

I do have a question related to jqGrid for what I'm doing. 

Actually, it is more a design question. 

As for what I plan to do, I need to be able to allow switching to a different year while keeping the same info other than
monthly breakdown data. See pic above.

May be showing the year as the main grid, and the current grid as subgrid? 
Year selection alternative way of doing will put a tremendous load on server and slow down the whole process due to requery server .

Is it a recommended way to do it?. What are your suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: @LuckyRiver: I'm not sure what is the best choice for you. Probably you pivot table it what you need. Probably `rotateColumnHeaders` method could essentially improve the look of the grid (you can call `$("#gridid").jqGrid(["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"]);` or to add additionally one more parameter with the height of the routed columns). It's difficult for me to recommend you something, because I don't really understand what information and how many you need to display.

Comment: @LuckyRiver: Probably posting of separate question, where you describe the problem more detailed, could be a good idea? I'm currently in the business trip and I write from hotel. Next week I'll have a little more time and could try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, Oleg. I think it's probably best to do this as a separate question. I will describe in detail the business needs.

Comment: Hello Oleg. Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224419/jqgrid-free-help-on-design-of-handling-multiple-yearly-calendars-with-monthly