# jqGrid Free : Help on design of handling multiple yearly calendars with monthly breakdown data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

As a side project, I'm writing a custom tailored resource management web app which will allow project managers within a company to input resources time allocation as a monthly breakdown. Currently it is working like a charm showing only one single year snapshot but as we go towards the end of the year, we need to able to foresee the upcoming months of next year. The column chooser comes handy to hide the months which have passed but as we will be going towards August or September month this year, we would like to be able to manage new or existing resources beginning of 
next coming year.

Here is what is currently displayed:
[image]
Thus, I'm stuck on how to design this correctly in a most effective way with jqGrid Free.

Initially, I could send back json data for 2 or more years in one shot and making the grid wider to show snapshots of the whole 2 years. That will probably work if I am able to preset column chooser not to show the whole monthly breakdown data of next year and user will be able to toggle new months of next year when the time comes. Still, I will need to do some trade-offs to display only the whole 2 years set only at the end of each year.

Other than that, I could stick only to one single year and add some previous year / next year buttons so user can go back and forth. But doing that, the server needs to send back and forth data to the client and slows down the whole process.

The amount data is reduced to the amount of projects and its allocated resources for the whole year breakdown in 12 months.

So as many projects with its fixed amount of resources are contributed to one or several projects. My first target is an average of 70 resources for 12 projects per year for one department.

Other department may have more or less, but the focus is for now only for one department.

As I have discussed in the other thread of implementing yearly using subgrids, this way I can repeat the same view of the current grid for different year as a subgrid. I'm still unsure whether or not it is good way to do it.

The way it is currently implemented is that JSON data are pushed to and pulled from server are done via rest services which perform CRUD operations in MySQL database. So, query a full grid with some grouping do take some time to render back to the client. Thus, I need to take into account performance issues.

Is pivot table something I need? Is there any example on this? Oleg mentionned in my other thread of rotateColumnHeaders, but I do not have clue on how to do this? But if this will solve what I'm asking, I definitely go for it.

Any suggestion how I should tackle this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

**More update:**
Here is the multiple footer rows that I got it working: 
[image: Multiple Footerows]

Comment: Could you include in your question some test data for one and two years? I made the demo https://jsfiddle.net/d8auuc5r/31/ as a starting point. jqPivot (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9)) could help to transform your *original input data* to the another form (close to the input data of my demo). Additionally jqPivot generate `colModel` for the grid. One can use frozen columns additionally or to hide/show columns for some years.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help for link and demo. I need to look and read the pivot concept first. 

So if I understand from a quick look, the demo shows a snapshot of two years frame which I could get inspired from your example. 

Very nice revolving column headers. Definitely will use it. 

However I still do not quite understand your demo and the pivot concept in provided link.

I am out of town this weekend but I will get back for the data. Code has evolved a lot since then

Comment: You are welcome! Pivot helps you to build your input data and to build dynamically `colModel` and another data with aggregation values. For example the input data could contain properties like `year`, `month`, `resourceTime`. If the input data contains only the data for one year, then the columns in `colModel` will contains only one one year. If you have many input element for the same year and month then the `resourceTime` could be summarized and the resulting data will contains the total sum of time resources for the month in the year. It's the main idea only.

Comment: 99% of the code of jqPivot method is analysing input data and building of 1) new `data` 2) `colModel` which corresponds the new data. The last step of jqPivot is call of jqGrid to display the data (optionally grouped) and then call two additional methods to call 1) `setGroupHeaders` to create grouping headers 2) to call `setFrozenColumns` to set first columns (`code` and `name`) frozen to simplify horizontal scrolling the grid, which has many columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the content/format of input data, which you have. For example, if the input data are already prepared for displaying in jqGrid like

```
var data = [
        {code:"A", name:"Project A",
            jan2017:1, feb2017:0, mar2017:0, apr2017:0,
            may2017:0, jun2017:0, jul2017:0, aug2017:0,
            sep2017:0, oct2017:0, nov2017:0, dec2017:1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A",
            jan2017:1, feb2017:1, mar2017:0, apr2017:0,
            may2017:1, jun2017:0, jul2017:0, aug2017:0,
            sep2017:0, oct2017:1, nov2017:0, dec2017:0}
    ];
```

then you can create the `colModel` directly. It could be something like

```
colModel: [
    { name: "code", label: "Code", width: 50, align: "center" },
    { name: "name", label: "Name", width: 70 },
    { name: "jan2017", label: "Jan", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "feb2017", label: "Feb", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "mar2017", label: "Mar", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "apr2017", label: "Apr", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "may2017", label: "May", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "jun2017", label: "Jun", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "jul2017", label: "Jul", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "aug2017", label: "Aug", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "sep2017", label: "Sep", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "oct2017", label: "Oct", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "nov2017", label: "Nov", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "dec2017", label: "Dec", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "jan2018", label: "Jan", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "feb2018", label: "Feb", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "mar2018", label: "Mar", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "apr2018", label: "Apr", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "may2018", label: "May", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "jun2018", label: "Jun", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "jul2018", label: "Jul", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "aug2018", label: "Aug", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "sep2018", label: "Sep", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "oct2018", label: "Oct", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "nov2018", label: "Nov", template: intTemplate },
    { name: "dec2018", label: "Dec", template: intTemplate }
]
```

where the column template is, for example, the following

```
var intTemplate = {
        width: 20, template: "integer",
        align: "center", editable: true
    };
```

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/d8auuc5r/31/ demonstrates the approach.

Another common case: you have input data, which correspond an item, which describes the resource of a project in a month. Something like

```
{code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 2, value: 3}
```

or like

```
{code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 2, week: 1, value: 1},
{code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 2, week: 2, value: 2}
```

The `week` or an additional fields could specify every resource more exactly. In the way one will have more as one item for a {code, name, year, month} combination. jqPivot will first of all **sort** the input data by properties, which you specifies, then group there and finally the value of some properties (`value` property in above example) will be aggregated with respect of some aggregation function, for example `sum` function.

jqPivot allows generates new data and the corresponding `colModel`. Then it calls `setGroupHeaders` to create grouping headers and optionally (if `frozenStaticCols: true` is used) it calls `setFrozenColumns` to make first columns frozen. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/d8auuc5r/76/ shows both approaches. It uses the following code:

```
$("#grid2").jqGrid("jqPivot", input, {
    xDimension: [
        { dataName: "name", width: 70, label: "Name" },
        { dataName: "code", width: 50, align: "center",
            skipGrouping: true, label: "Code" }
    ],
    yDimension: [
        { dataName: "year" },
        { dataName: "month", sorttype: "integer",
            label: function (options) { return monthNames[options.yData - 1]; }
        }
    ],
    aggregates: [
        {
            member: "value",
            aggregator: "sum",
            template: "integer",
            align: "center",
            width: 20,
            editable: true
        }
    ],
    frozenStaticCols: true,
    useColSpanStyle: true
},
{
    cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
    autoResizing: { compact: true },
    pager: true,
    width: 360,
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    caption: "Pivot test",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: false,
    inlineEditing: { keys: true },
    navOptions: { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false },
    inlineNavOptions: { add: true, edit: true },
    onInitGrid: function () {
        var $self = $(this),
            p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
            toRotate = [], i;
        for (i = 2; i < p.colModel.length; i++) {
            toRotate.push(p.colModel[i].name);
        }

        $self.jqGrid("rotateColumnHeaders", toRotate);
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid")
.jqGrid("inlineNav");
```

where

```
var input = [
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 1, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 2, value: 2},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 2, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 3, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 4, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 5, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 6, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 7, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 8, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 9, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 10, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 11, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2017, month: 12, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 1, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 2, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 3, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 4, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 5, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 6, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 7, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 8, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 9, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 10, value: 1},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 11, value: 0},
        {code:"A", name:"Project A", year: 2018, month: 12, value: 1},
    ],
    monthNames = [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
```

One will have some problems with editing such grid, because the columns will be generated dynamically. I just want to explain main ideas of jqPivot and not explain here all features of jqPivot and free jqGrid in general.

Comment: Wow very nice demo as always. Currently, I have a bunch of resources which will need to be expanded for one more year. How about doing it for full 5 years ahead instead of 2, does it deteriorate  performance?  I guess I have to experiment first the pivot to see if CRUD operation mechanism still work and if not, how hard to modify current code to get it working. I think I have plenty of information to go back to do more sandbox work. Thanks again Oleg for explaining and your precious time to answer and to write demo. I believe you pretty much answer my question more than I have hoped for.

Comment: Hi Oleg,

I need to achieve as below:

Keeping it what it is right now, eg for both Pivot and no Pivot one,

How to add two more rows in the same grid with the 12 months pattern, but with other external total values which need to be displayed below the total of all sub groups to compute the sum of those 2 totals.

eg.
    Jan ... Dec
proj A        1  ... 1 
 sub total    1 ...  1
proj B        1 ...  12
 sub total    1 ...  2
  TOTAL    2      3
 Other Total     1  ... 1  
  Sum               1  ... 2
  
How the json data is structured and how do it with jqgrid?

Any tip?

Comment: Update: I found out the solution of my new question which was already asked years ago which is to use multiple footer rows which was also answered by Oleg. :)

Comment: @LuckyRiver: OK, good news! I am very busy now with projects for my customers and just forgot to answer on your previous comment (which was not full clear for me). In any way, it's good to know that you found the solution. Probably other readers have the same problem too.

Comment: It was not that clear unless I attach a picture. Here is what I was able to achieve using the solution of multiple footrows. But most of the work is done on the backend though with less code with jqGrid. Next time, I will do more homework searching and reading first since most of the questions may have already been asked and answered. See image I've added above.